# cls behaviour in inherited classmethod of a decorated class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-decorators, class-method

I'm trying to make some validations for the class methods of a class using one of the parameters used when calling them.

To do this, I'm using a decorator for the class that will apply a decorator to the required methods, which will perform a validation function using one of the parameters in the function.

This all works well for the base class (for this example I will call it `Parent`).

However, if I make another class which inherits `Parent`, (for this example I will call it `Child`), the inherited decorated classmethod no longer behaves normally.

The `cls` parameter inside the classmethod for the `Child` class is not `Child` as expected, but is `Parent` instead.

Taking the following example

```
import inspect


def is_number(word):
    if word.isdigit():
        print('Validation passed')
    else:
        raise Exception('Validation failed')


class ClassDecorator(object):

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.validators = args

    def __decorateMethod(self):
        def wrapped(method):
            def wrapper(cls, word, *args, **kwargs):
                for validator in self.validators:
                    validator(word)
                return method(word, *args, **kwargs)
            return wrapper
        return wrapped

    def __call__(self, cls):
        for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls):
            if name == 'shout':
                decoratedMethod = self.__decorateMethod()(method)
                setattr(cls, name, classmethod(decoratedMethod))
        return cls


@ClassDecorator(is_number)
class Parent(object):

    @classmethod
    def shout(cls, word):
        print('{} is shouting {}'.format(cls, word))

    @classmethod
    def say(cls):
        print('{} is talking'.format(cls))


class Child(Parent):
    pass


Parent.shout('123')
Child.shout('321')
```

Will result in the following output:

```
Validation passed
<class '__main__.Parent'> is shouting 123
Validation passed
<class '__main__.Parent'> is shouting 321
```

My questions are:

- Why does the classmethod for `Child` get called with `Parent` as cls
- Is it possible using this design to get the wanted behaviour?

**P.S.**: I've tried this on both Python 2.7.10 and Python 3.5.2 and have gotten the same behaviour

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are decorating the *bound class method*; it is this object that holds on to `Parent` and passes it into the original `shout` function when called; whatever `cls` is bound to in your `wrapper()` method is not passed in and ignored.

Unwrap classmethods first, you can get to the underlying function object with the `__func__` attribute:

```
def __call__(self, cls):
    for name, method in inspect.getmembers(cls):
        if name == 'shout':
            decoratedMethod = self.__decorateMethod()(method.__func__)
            setattr(cls, name, classmethod(decoratedMethod))
    return cls
```

You now have to take into account that your wrapper is handling an *unbound* function too, so pass on the `cls` argument or manually bind:

```
# pass in cls explicitly:
return method(cls, word, *args, **kwargs)

# or bind the descriptor manually:
return method.__get__(cls)(word, *args, **kwargs)
```